# Basic Python - can't get IF statement to work when comparing hardcoded int variable with dynamic int variable via input()

Tags: python, if-statement

Anyone know why the below always triggers the "else" statement even when I provide age of 16?

```
age_to_drive = 16

print("Hello! So you want a car? Hmmmm let's get some info first.")
age = input("How old are you? ")

print(age)

if age == age_to_drive:
    print("Here's the keys to your brand new car!")
else:
    print("Sorry, you're a child!")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Python is a typed language.

Comment: Change `age = input(...)` to `age = int(input(...))`.  Without wrapping it in `int()`, it will be a string (in Python 3 anyway - in Python 2 it would in fact be an integer).

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot